# BigQuery + Amazon Athena + Presto: limits on number of partitions and columns

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

Based on Google BigQuery documentation, BigQuery has the following limits (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas):

> 1) Maximum number of partitions per partitioned table — 4,000.
>
> 2) Maximum columns in a table, query result, or view definition — 10,000

Based on Amazon Athena documentation: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html):

> Maximum number of partitions per partitioned table — 20,000

Is there any hard limits on the number of columns for AWS Athena or for Presto?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any hard limits on the number of columns for AWS Athena or for Presto?

Unfortunately I can't answer for AWS Athena, but I can answer for Presto.

No, there are no explicit hard limits for number of columns. *In theory*, you are limited by available memory and maximum size of collections in Java.

In practice, however, when you have more than 10k columns, you can experience increased planning times. With higher number of columns (perhaps about 100k and more), you will hit JVM byte code length limits in classes generated for the purpose of processing your queries.

Comment: Another limitation in Athena is that if you use `ORDER BY` in queries where there are a lot of columns you may run into the error "Query exhausted at this scale factor". This is caused by the node doing the sorting running out of memory.

Comment: @Theo In Presto .172 we didn't have distributed sort yet.